# Prolog - How to get a list of lists made with all possible paths on a tree?

Tags: list, tree, prolog

I want to build a predicate in Prolog that returns a list of lists with all tree paths.

So, I have these predicates:

```
component(solarSystem, earth).
component(solarSystem, mars).
component(earth, water).
component(earth, land).
```

The point is to get a list like this:

```
?- tree_list(solarSystem, L).
L = [(solarSystem, [(earth,[water,land]),mars])]
```

Let's assume that the predicate `get_childs(solarSystem, L)` (**I already have this predicate implemented and working**) returns a list with all the solar system childs, like this:

```
/* ALREADY IMPLEMENTED */
?- get_childs(solarSystem, L).
L = [earth, water, land, mars]
```

Any suggestions, please?
Thank you

BTW: I saw this question ([Tree path in a List of Lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10065675/tree-path-in-a-list-of-lists)) but the solution is not exactly what I'm looking for. I have the information on my knowledge base just like I posted here, the point is to make a code receiving the root and then get all the paths.